# formatting message logging policy in API manager

Tags: dataweave, mule4

im trying to write dataweave inside message logging policy in API manager using syntax like `#[%dw 2.0 output application/json --- {"chrome_appid": attributes.headers.chrome_appid, "blah": "blah blah"}]` but that doesnt seem to work. it saves to policy but logs are not generated. simple syntax like `#[payload]` and `#[attributes]` works. how do i format my dataweave code for api manager to read it correctly? I want some key-values from the header (or payload) displayed in the message logging. I'm trying to do this for flex gateway 1.3

Comment: Is the logging policy for Mule or for Flex? What is the log output with attributes and with your expression? Version of Mule/Flex?

Comment: this is for flex 1.3

Answer (score 1):

Flex Gateway supports only a sub-set of the DataWeave language. Specifically it doesn't support [object value construction](https://docs.mulesoft.com/policies/policies-flex-dataweave-support#unavailable-value-constructors-for-types). It seems that the intention is to use the DataWeave sub-set just to write strings.

My advise would be not to use a JSON output since it is not fully supported. Use normal strings logs and if you really need JSON logs transform them outside Flex Gateway with a script or some other tool.

If you still want to try to generate JSON you can construct it using string concatenations, which is a hack and can eventually led to invalid JSONs. Note that you also need to do all escaping by hand which is time consuming.

Example of the not recommended option:

```
#["{\"chrome_appid\":" ++ attributes.headers.chrome_appid ++ ", \"blah\": \"blah blah\"}"]  // Not recommended, error prone
```